# Laravel passport: Key path "file:///tmp/SomeFileName.key" does not exist or is not readable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

In my environment I use 2 client applications implemented in Laravel and one server application implemented in Lumen.

When the user logs in on client1 side, the token for this user is written into the Database, same thing happens on client2.

From there on I send the bearer token in the Authentication-header of each request, because the endpoints of my Lumen application should be protected like this:

web.php:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => '/api/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() use ($router) {
    $router->get('/someEndpoint', 'SomeController@index');
});
```

At the beginning when I only had 1 client, I had a problem to go past this middleware, because I always got an "Unauthenticated".
Then I tried to give my Lumen Application the same private + public keys as my client. This worked and I got past my Api guard and could read my data.

My next approach was to add another client. I tried to give my client2 the same private + public key as my client1 (and my Lumen app).
After trying to send requests to my Lumen app, client1 still worked, but my client2 got following exception:

> Key path "file:///tmp/someRandomName.key" does not exist or is not
> readable

I understand that inside this file there is the private/public key written and there is a problem when a second client tries to call the API.

1. Question:
   Is this approach a "no go" or is it possible to use 1 private key for all of my clients?
2. Question:
   If my configuration is a "no go" how do I tell my Lumen part which key he should use to decipher the
   Bearer Token?